# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List' / postUrl method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried but cannot seem to get passed this. I am trying to post some variables to a webView using Flutter's postUrl method, but I keep getting this error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have also tried finding an example of anyone using this method online and cannot find anything. Someone please help.

page.dart:

````
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyPaymentWidget());
}

class MyPaymentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RouteArgument routeArgument;
  MyPaymentWidget({Key key, this.routeArgument}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyPaymentWidgetState createState() => new _MyPaymentWidgetState();
}

class _MyPaymentWidgetState extends State<MyPaymentWidget> {

  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  Uint8List postData;
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true, 
        title: Text(
          S.of(context).instant_eft_payment,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
        ),
      ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: progress < 1.0
                    ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                    : Container()),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://example.com/",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                    inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                    )
                  ),
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                    webView.postUrl(
                      url: 'https://example.com/', 
                      postData: "Amount=1&TransactionReference=some trans ref&BankReference=bank ref&Customer=thiscustomer&isTest=true");
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.goBack();
                    }
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.goForward();
                    }
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.reload();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `postData` argument to `postUrl` is a `Uint8List` but you're passing it a `String`. I'm assuming that this is supposed to be either the `codeUnits` of the string (the UTF-16 representation) or the UTF-8 encoding.

Try passing one of these as the `postData` argument:

```dart
Uint8List.fromList(myPostData.codeUnits);
```

or

```dart
// This requires dart:convert
Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(myPostData));
```

Comment: `codeUnits` is a UTF-16 encoding of the string. OP wants the `utf8.encode` option.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, used the utf8 option and error is gone. I was able to run a successful test. Just one more question: does the utf8 encoding change the values on the string? I ask because "myPostData" is actually a string with a hash value concatenated to it. When I do the utf encoding, the hashCheck fails.

Comment: @DotComLabZA Dart uses UTF-16 to internally represent the string. When you convert it to UTF-8, it is a different value so it makes sense for it to have a different hash code. (There's also the fact that you're generating the hash code of a `Uint8List` as opposed to one for a `String` which may have wildly different hash code calculation implementations.) As long as the original string doesn't contain any characters that UTF-8 doesn't directly support, you should easily be able to convert it back to a native Dart string using `utf8.decode`.

Comment: @Abion47 The explanation above does help my understanding of what's going on, thanks. However I am struggling to apply it. My specific situation is that I need to load a webView and in order to successfully do that I need to post some parameters to the webpage (which I am using the `postUrl()`method to do), otherwise the webpage doesnt load. The above solution fixed my console errors, but not quite the use case as it changes the data being posted to the webpage which means the webpage is still not loading correctly. So is there a way to post `myPostData` without encoding/changing it?

Comment: @DotComLabZA What package are you using?

Comment: @Abion47 These are the packages I'm importing: `import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';`

Comment: How is the hash code suffix being generated? Hash codes usually start out as a byte, an integer, or a byte array, and only get serialized to a string later. Perhaps you could change how you are serializing the hash code to something that is more web or UTF-8 friendly.

Comment: Spot on. Firstly to clarify, the webpage requires the parameters plus the hash of the parameters to be posted onto the page. So my process goes: 1. myData is a string of parameters 2. myData is utf8 encoded and stored in dataBytes 3. dataBytes is converted to hash string and stored in hashedString 4. hashedString is concetenated to myData and stored as myPostData. 5. `Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(myPostData));`. That is what I am doing currently.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing same problem my hash is changing `Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(myPostData));` while performing this.